# Qt embedded processes not all keys

Tags: qt, keyboard, embedded, arm, qkeyevent

I use Qt Embedded and I have a board with some keypad. I use eventFilter and check for QKeyEvent for my widget, but for only two buttons Qt doesn't react to. eventFilter isn't called. Here is code:

```
bool eventFilter(QObject* parent, QEvent* event)
{
  qDebug() << "entered";
  switch (event->type())
  {
    case QEvent::KeyPress:
    {
      QKeyEvent* key_event = qobject_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
      qDebug() << key_event->key();
    }
  }
}
```

But physic keys work and driver too. I can listen it from /dev/event2.

Has anybody struggled with it?
Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to add some more relevant details or no one is going to be able to help you...

Comment: Your widget must have focus to get events.  Add an application filter if you want to see all events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a test, you could try installing a QWSServer::KeyboardFilter before instantiating the App. And see if the QWSServer is getting the key.

If not, then I would suggest looking at the keymap used by the QWS server (look up environment variable QWS_KEYBOARD). Both the default US key map and in my case, the custom gb.qmap didn't map all the keys.